# CAST(SEC_TO_TIME not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql (MySQL) statement which outputs the difference in seconds between 2 datetimes in each record (the output from a previous select statement), this is working correctly -

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('<c:out value="${row.acktime}" />')
- UNIX_TIMESTAMP('<c:out value="${row.ts}" />') as tdiff
```

The output is typically in thousands of seconds (5523, 1892 etc) and I want to display that as hh:mm:ss so I -

```
select CAST(SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('<c:out value="${row.acktime}" />')
- UNIX_TIMESTAMP('<c:out value="${row.ts}" />') AS CHAR) as tdiff
```

but this produces no output (and doesn't throw an error). What am I doing wrong?

Regards
Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarrely  CAST was causing the issue, removing it resulted in the correct display.

Comment: I have just tried with the char conversion in phpmyadmin's online demo and it worked just fine. Btw, conversion to char is not needed, since the time data type appears as text anyway in the results.

Comment: I spoke to soon, sometimes SEC_TO_TIME produces no output, removing it results in seconds shown everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TIME_FORMAT` function, (here's the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)). Your query will look like the one below:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(<some value>),'%Hh %im');
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9deb/106/0)**.

Comment: No, you do not need to use time_format(), direct conversion to char should also work. Actually, time data type is pretty much a string already.

Comment: The question does not mention any example value so answer had to rely on  assumption(s).